# Como checar um atributo do tipo objeto em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu recebo o seguinte objeto:

```
obj = {
    fernando: {
        nome: 'Fernando',
        idade: 21
    },
    tiago: {
        nome: 'tiago',
        idade: NaN
    },
    total: 2
}
```

Como podem ver, eu recebo um objeto onde cada atributo pode ser outro objeto, e também pode ser um atributo do tipo inteiro.

Como faço para checar cada "pessoa".idade é `Number`????

EDIT: Preciso checar "N" valores(pessoas), e não apenas uma específica...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para aceder às propriedades de um objeto podes fazer de duas maneiras:

```js
var obj = {
    fernando: {
        nome: 'Fernando',
        idade: 21
    },
    tiago: {
        nome: 'tiago',
        idade: NaN
    },
    total: 2
};

console.log(obj.tiago.nome); // dá tiago
console.log(obj['tiago']['nome']); // dá tiago
```

Ambas funcionam mas a primeira é mais usada quando sabes o nome da propriedade de antemão.

Para saber o tipo da variável/propriedade podes usar o `typeof`:

```js
console.log(typeof 0); // number
console.log(typeof 4); // number
console.log(typeof NaN); // number
console.log(typeof 'texto'); // string
```

Se juntares a isso métodos de objetos podes encontrar o que precisas:

```js
var obj = {
    fernando: {
        nome: 'Fernando',
        idade: 21
    },
    tiago: {
        nome: 'tiago',
        idade: NaN
    },
    total: 2
};

// quantos têm idade válida
var nrValidos = Object.keys(obj).filter(nome => obj[nome].idade).length;
console.log(nrValidos); // 1

// quantas pessoas têm a propriedade idade
var nrEntradas = Object.keys(obj).filter(nome => obj[nome].hasOwnProperty('idade')).length;
console.log(nrEntradas); // 2

// quais as pessoas que têm a propriedade idade válida
var nomes = Object.keys(obj).filter(nome => obj[nome].idade);
console.log(nomes); // ["fernando"]
```

Se verificares somente `obj[nome].idade` dá false para `NaN` e `0`. Se os quiseres distinguir podes usar `isNaN`. `isNaN(NaN) //dá  true`

Comment: Sergio, você tem usado as arrow functions sem transpilar o código? Isso já é razoavelmente suportado?

Comment: @bfavaretto por acaso não sei se o IE11 suporta (imagino que não), os outros acho que já suportam. Como trabalho em ambiente que é transpilado pela Babel ganhei o hábito de usar ES6+.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode iterar as chaves do objeto usando [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) e verificar se é um número usando [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp):

```js
var obj = {
  fernando: {
    nome: 'Fernando',
    idade: 21
  },
  tiago: {
    nome: 'tiago',
    idade: NaN
  },
  lucas: {
    nome: 'Lucas',
    idade: 23
  },
  total: 2
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!isNaN(obj[key].idade))
      console.log(obj[key].nome + " possui idade");
});
```